# invalid sql type (slice) for postgres

Tags: postgresql, go, migration, go-gorm

I want to AutoMigrate my Model but I get this error when running up:

`invalid sql type (slice) for postgres`

Here is my struct:

```
type Tracking struct {
    ServerID    int64
    Tracks      []map[string]interface{}
}
```

Im using gorm to work with the DB. (github.com/jinzhu/gorm)

The error comes from: `AutoMigrate(&Tracking{})`

Is there a solution to this?
Thanks already

Comment: `[]map[string]interface{}` is not compatible with database types. You'll need to write your own scanner as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073209/persisting-custom-set-data-type-using-gorm-golang)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Persisting custom set data type using GORM golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61073209/persisting-custom-set-data-type-using-gorm-golang)

Comment: What is that `Tracks` column type in you db migration file?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is `gorm` and most SQL databases don't support slices as a data type. To work around this you need to tell gorm to set up a `many to many` relationship table.

```
Table1 <----> (Table1/Table2) <----> Table2
```

I was attempting the same thing, the [gorm documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html) advised the following and it worked for me:

```golang
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Languages []Language `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}

type Language struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name string
}
```

Taking a guess at yours I would do:

```golang
type Tracking struct {
    ServerID    int64
    Tracks      []Tracks `gorm:"many2many:tracking_tracks;"`
}

type Tracks struct {
    gorm.Model
    Text      string
}
```

This sets up three tables as previously mentioned, your `trackings` table, your `tracks` table and a third one called `tracking_tracks` which will store the `id` to `id` relationship (many to many)

It's then important to note that for data you are querying from one table where there is a relationship with another table, you will need to `Preload()` those tables.

Using the gorm example you would do the following

```golang
var users []User
db.Preload("Languages").Find(&users)
```

Not doing this will return the `users` with the `languages` column empty.

If `many to many` doesn't suit you can try a `has many` or `one to many` relationship if that is more suitable https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html