# how to represent inet column type of postgres for a GORM model?

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am trying to use `inet` column type of postgres for one of my GORM models

my application is a gin-gonic based micro-service which is backed by GORM package for ORM. The default GORM postgres dialect doesn't support this datatype currently. What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: You need to implement Scanner & Valuer interface for the custom type [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61157971/4207306)

Comment: What Rono said, or you can use types that already implement the two interfaces, like https://godoc.org/github.com/jackc/pgtype#Inet for example.